# Show hint text with drag-and-drop (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, drag-and-drop, hint

How to show text/hint when the dragged Object is on the allowed drop area?

On top of showing the DragDropEffect as below, I'd like to show a small hint text saying like "Drop the item here to add it to list".

```
Private Sub grid_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.DragEventArgs)
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(List(Of myObject))) Then
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move
    Else
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/moving-data-grid-rows-using-drag-and-drop) (Moving WPF DataGrid Rows using Drag and Drop). I know it's C# but the idea is there.

He hooks into the OnMouseLeftButtonDown to begin the drag operation. You could add setting a drop target hint visible (or some other visual indicator) and hide it in the OnMouseLeftButtonUp event when he resets the DragDrop.

Sorry, my original answer was off target.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are after but with the extent of the available information it is hard to give much more than the below. Simply add a label to the form set its `visibility = hidden` Then when the dragged item passes the check for valid item to drop, change the label `visibility = Visible` when the mouse leaves the drop area or the button to drop is released always reset the label `visibility = hidden`... Another way of achieving this would be to get the pointer position and set the label x,y position to that when the visibility = visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have done exactly this in one of my own programs. The way I did it was I had a label with `InfoLabel.Visible = False` in the designer and I then have the following code operating on it:

```
Private Sub DrgEnter(Sender As System.Object, DragArgs As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles ListViewQA.DragEnter
    InfoLabel.Text = "Hint Text Here"
    InfoLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(MousePosition.X - (Me.Location.X - 3), MousePosition.Y - (Me.Location.Y + 32))
    InfoLabel.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub MoveLabel() Handles ListViewQA.DragOver
    InfoLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(MousePosition.X - (Me.Location.X - 3), MousePosition.Y - (Me.Location.Y + 32))
End Sub

Private Sub HideInfoLabel() Handles ListViewQA.DragLeave, InfoLabel.MouseMove
    InfoLabel.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub DragDropAdd(Sender As System.Object, DropArgs As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles ListViewQA.DragDrop
    InfoLabel.Visible = False
    'Put Drop Handling code here
End Sub
```

Hope this helps, and I have can give you more code relating to this if you need it!

Answer (score 0):

try using the mouse enter event and make it check for mouse dragging , from there you should be able to create a label and make it follow the mouse using this code

```
dim point as new point 
point.x = windows.forms.cursor.position.x
point.y = windows.forms.cursor.position.y
```

and making it visible only when dragging